# Как получить значение из ссесии

Tags: php, yii2

есть такой код

```
if ($ch4 = Yii::$app->request->get('ch4') == true) {
    $ch4 = Yii::$app->request->get('ch4');
} else {
    $ch4 = $session->get('ch4');
}
$session->set('ch4', $ch4);
```

где `Yii::$app->request->get` получение гет запроса, `$session->get`-получение значений из сессии и запись в сессию `$session->set` эти танцы с бубнами были придуманы для того что бы если клиент нажимает на браузере кнопку назад. Но теперь получается следующая ситуация запрос сh4 может быть пустым (не выбрал его клиент ну а предыдущим запросом клиент выбирал что ch4=2 и в сессию теперь записалось такое значение. по этому я бы хотел иметь возможность получать значение из сесии толь ко если клиент нажал кнопку назад на браузере. Такое возможно?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать HTTP_REFERER

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade а как хоть для примера ?

Comment: if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
   //Тут ваш функционал
}

Comment: Вариант с historyAPI и сегментами в URL неприемлемы? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25806609/6645679